# Why my simple form is not sending post data in php?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, form-data

I'm trying to send data over post request, but the post array seems to be empty. I've tried all the methods i.e., get, post, and request but I'm getting the same result all the time, please help me sort this out.

Here is my code snippet:

Html File:

```html
 <form action="question-paper.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="quespaper" value="formValue"/>
    <button type="button" onclick="openExam();" class="btn btn-outline-success" style="margin- 
      top:15px;"> Start </button>
</form>
```

PHP File:

```php
print("Post array<br>");
var_dump($_POST);
```

JavaScript code:

```js
function openExam(){
   window.open('question-paper.php', '_blank');
}
```

Comment: You don't have any submit button in your form, but you do have a normal button that will only execute some JavaScript. We need to see that JavaScript (the `openExam()` function), or we won't have a clue how (or even if) you're actually submitting the form. _Side note:_ When you format code blocks in your question, use three backticks, not three single quotes.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71887613/edit) your question to include all necessary code instead of adding it in comments.

Comment: 'function openExam(){
                window.open('question-paper.php', '_blank');
            }' here is my javascript code

Comment: `window.open('question-paper.php', '_blank')` won't submit the form. It simply opens that URL in a new window/tab and has nothing to do with your form. If the idea to simply submit the form in a new window/tab, add `target="_blank"` to the open form tag, remove `type="button"` and `onclick="openExcam()"` from the button. If you're trying to do something else, you need to add a detailed explanation to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the code below would call a JavaScript function. That function would then maybe be responsible to submit the form, so maybe add that code as we cannot see it on your post.

```
<button type="button" onclick="openExam();"
```

Alternatively you can remove the `onclick="openExam();"` part and just add the parameter `type="submit"` to the button, then it will submit the form immediately when pressed

Comment: The code was not formatted correctly. OP had type=button

Comment: You can submit a form, with button type="button" as long as you use JavaScript to do it. Here it's a matter of choosing which way to go, since at the time of my writing there was no reference about the JavaScript code on the page.

Comment: As I said, when I answered, the JavaScript part was not there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form action="question-paper.php" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="quespaper" value="formValue"/>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" style="margin-top:15px;"> Start </button>
</form>
```

I changed the type from `button` to `submit`. It will automatically go to the file mentioned in the `action` of the form tag.

I am sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

If your openexam works, then no need to have a form at all OR not need to have JavaScript

So EITHER this (which will send the hidden field)  - add the method="post" if needed. If post IS needed, then you cannot use the window.location

```html
<form action="question-paper.php" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="quespaper" value="formValue"/>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" 
  style="margin-top:15px;"> Start </button>
</form>
```

OR

```
  <button type="button" onclick="openExam()" style="btn btn-outline-success" 
  style="margin-top:15px;"> Start </button>
```